# Выводить всплывающее окно только 1 раз за сессию

Tags: javascript, cookie, всплывающее-окно

На сайте выводится всплыв. окно спустя 13 секунд, на каждой странице. То есть человек зашел на сайт, через 13 сек. появилось окно, перешел на другую страницу, и там тоже через 13 сек появилось окно. Можно сделать так чтоб окно появлялось только 1 раз, неважно на какой странице находился бы посетитель? А в идеале было бы если появлялось 2 раза, но это вряд ли возможно реализовать... 
Знаю, что нужно делать какие-то манипуляции с куками, только не хватает для этого знаний, может кто подскажет что именно нужно прописать?
Вот собственно код вывода окна:

```
if ( $('.js-form-get-roll').length ) {
    if ( !$.cookie('roll_popup_sent') ) {
        setTimeout(function() {
            open_form_roll();
        }, 13000);
    }

    function open_form_roll() {
        ruler_to_log();
        $('body').addClass('open-form-roll');
        yaCounter24815432.reachGoal('roll_show');
         $('.js-roll-drum').css('transform', 'rotate(-216deg)');
    }

    $('.js-form-get-roll-close').click(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $('body').removeClass('open-form-roll');
        if ( !$.cookie('roll_popup_sent') && !$.cookie('roll_popup1') ) {
            setTimeout(function() { 
                $.cookie('roll_popup1', 'value');
                open_form_roll();
            }, 40000);
        }
    });
```

Comment: localstorage лучше может

Comment: Есть еще `sessionStorage`. Если что-то нужно отслеживать в текущем "сеансе" работы и в одной вкладке - самое то. https://learn.javascript.ru/localstorage#sessionstorage

Answer (score 0):

```js
const LIMIT_IMPRESSION = 2;
const POPUP_COUNTER_KEY = 'popupCounter'

function showPopup() {
  console.log('Тут логика открытия попапа');
}

function checkDiscountPopupCounter(limit) {
  let currentCounter = +localStorage.getItem(POPUP_COUNTER_KEY);
  if (!currentCounter) {
    showPopup();
    localStoraeg.setItem(POPUP_COUNTER_KEY, 1);
    return;
  }
  
  if (currentCounter < LIMIT_IMPRESSION) {
    showPopup();
    localStoraeg.setItem(POPUP_COUNTER_KEY, currentCounter++);
  }
  
  return;
}
```